# Condense steps from htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I Currently have the following htaccess code below which is to add a trailing slash and make sure it's https and www. (This is a wordpress site)

The issue is that if a URL is provided without a https, www or a slash.

E.g. - http://example.com/test

It requires 2 hops to get to it.

- http://example.com/test - ORIGINAL (then 301's to below)
- https://example.com/test (then 301's to below)
- https://www.example.com/test/

How can I do this all in one step in the htaccess so it gets from http://example.com/test TO https://www.example.com/test/

```
# BEGIN HTTPS Redirection Plugin
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END HTTPS Redirection Plugin

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you:

```
# 301 redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# 301 redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Please, test via, for example, http://redirectcheck.com/

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work with wordpress and pretty permalinks code which the second piece of htacess in my example. It results in 404 not found issues when on subpages with a wordpress site.

Comment: Weird, I'm using this on a number of WP installations. Maybe you forgot to switch WP itself to using HTTPS?

Comment: When you say forgot to switch WP itself. IS this just adding https://www in the general options for both WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL)? I've got it set there too.

Comment: Adding https in general options. Both options should have `https://www.yourdomain.com` (I assume that's your 'main' URL model you want to use).